# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay crashes app in release but not debug

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging

I'm using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay to set up an animation in my app. The app is crashing in release but not debug. The crash log looks like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35736e3e objc_release + 14
1   stky                            0x0010e096 -[OPLabel executeStrikethroughAnimationWithCompletion:] (OPLabel.m:142)
2   Foundation                      0x37a6992c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 408
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37207a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37207692 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37206268 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3718949e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
7   CoreFoundation                  0x37189366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
8   GraphicsServices                0x32096432 GSEventRunModal + 130
9   UIKit                           0x3390de76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
10  stky                            0x000f7224 main (main.m:16)
11  stky                            0x000f71d8 0xf6000 + 4568
```

So as far as I can tell, it's the attempt to call the delayed method that's crashing the app. But beyond that I'm not sure what the issue is, nor do I know how to debug (since it doesn't happen in debug mode). Help? Thanks.

Comment: can u post ur part of code here?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i guess you may refer some premitive value instead of object else it will be analyzed after seeing code and if you are using premitive one then use (id)value and try if this works

Another common cause of this is an object being called upon that's already been released from memory. Try tracing this with NSZombieEnabled

Comment: Thanks. Here's what's interesting: if I clear out the body of the method being called with the delay, it still crashes; in other words, it seems to be the act of calling the method itself that causes the problem. I don't understand how that's even possible -- according to Apple's docs an object is retained when you call performSelector:withObject:afterDelay.

Answer (score 0):

The object you pass as parameter to performSelector is freed more aggressively in Release mode. You should retain it to make sure it is still in memory after the delay (even with a 0.0 delay!).